# How to choose an index item by default in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to choose the index-0 item by default in React. Here is my code:

```
<div
      role="tabpanel"
      hidden={value !== index}
      id={`scrollable-auto-tabpanel-${index}`}
      aria-labelledby={`scrollable-auto-tab-${index}`}
      {...other}
    >
      {value === index && (
        <Box p={3}>
          <Typography>{children}</Typography>
        </Box>
      )}
</div>
```

here is its function:

```
function a11yProps(index) {
  return {
    id: `scrollable-auto-tab-${index}`,
    "aria-controls": `scrollable-auto-tabpanel-${index}`,
  };
}
```

So, I want to choose scrollable-auto-tab-0 && scrollable-auto-tabpanel-0 by default.

Comment: In what context do u mean "choose"?

Comment: in ${index} I am getting numbers between 0 to X. And I want to choose scrollable-auto-tab-0 which is the first value as default value after creating an indexed ids'.